# convert period to time using lubridate withing R

Tags: r, lubridate

I've edited my post to include some data and also to break things up into pieces.

I am trying to fill in some missing time values in a timeseries. To do this I would like to take the time difference between two records before and after a missing value and use that to create a new time. When I try the below (which is in a loop), I get an error of not being able to convert a period to a time. (Below this code I have added some data and a toy example)

```
bottom$GPS_UTC_time_hms[ii] =   
  as.period(
    bottom$GPS_UTC_time_hms[ii-1] + 
    as.duration(
      (interval(
         bottom$GPS_UTC_time_hms[ii-1],    
         bottom$GPS_UTC_time_hms[ii+1]
      ))/2
    )
   )

Error: Can't convert <Period> to <time>.


## When building this example, there is an additional error that appears to
## have to do with supplying an origin. It seems to be supplied with
## lubridate ("1970-01-01 UTC"), however the error asks for me to supply
## the origin and I can't figure out how to do that

library(lubridate)

# First I read data with times in a string format and a missing value
a = c("11:18:09", NA, "11:18:21" )

# Next I used lubridate to convert them to hour-minute-second format
a1 = hms(a)
# Warning message:
# In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
#   Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
a1
# [1] "11H 18M 9S"  NA            "11H 18M 21S"


# What I would like to do is find the midpoint between the times 1 and 3 so  # that I can assign that midpoint to the missing value for time 2 (i.e., "11H # 18M 15S")

# So, following an example I found online, I attempted to add the half         # duration of the interval between the two dates to the period from the first # value. 
# (So, "11H 18M 15S")
ap = as.period(a1[1]) 
ap
#[1] "11H 18M 9S"

# Below I get an error about needing the origin to be applied
ab_int = interval(a1[1], b1[3], tzone = "UTC")
# Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(x, tz = tz) : 'origin' must be supplied

# When I do things broken out like this, I don't get to these last two steps
# because of the error above
ab_dur = as.duration(ab_int)/2

a1[2] = ap + ab_dur

# this last step has an additional error when not done in this simplified    # manner. In the full code - which I originally posted above - I am trying to # put this value back into the GPS_UTC_time_hms variable, and I think that is # where the original mismatch error came into play: 

# Error: Can't convert <Period> to <time>.
# In addition: Warning message:
# tz(): Don't know how to compute timezone for object of class hms/difftime; returning "UTC". This warning will become an error in the next major version of lubridate.

# In this toy version, I never get to this error step because of the origin error.
```

Comment: Can you provide some data, e.g., `bottom$GPS_UTC_time_hms[1:3]`

Comment: See [this page](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/lubridate-package.html) for information on the various terms used in lubridate.  Working with times can be confusing, so it's important to get your terminology right.  As @David said, without data, it's impossible to know exactly what you're trying to do and why you're getting the error.

Comment: Thanks for your input thus far. I have edited my post to include some data and a toy version.